# Select Input on Label Click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to search data
but i have multiple label like firstname,lastname and Username
and only one input
i want to place different placeholder based on the label clicked
how this possible with jquery and javascript

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Please be more specific with your problem provide more description about your issue and tell us what you have done so far and where you stucked?

Comment: You just need to bind click on label and associate its text as a placeholder of the search input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```js
$('label').on('click', function () {
   $('input#text').attr('placeholder', $(this).text());
});
```

```css
label, input {display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Firstname</label>
<label>Lastname</label>
<label>Username</label>
<input id="text" type="text">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.searchLabels').click(function(e){
     $('#searchTxt').prop('placeholder',$(this).text())
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='searchTxt' type="text"  placeholder="" >
 
 <br/><label class='searchLabels'>firstname</label>
 <br/><label class='searchLabels'>lastname </label>
 <br/><label class='searchLabels'>Username </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Property of an input using jquery

```
$('input').attr("placeholder", "your text");
```

See the demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3u29vrrv/2/)